# How to read server logs using java code on live(currently code under execution) or executed processes and show it on UI?

Tags: java, logging, console

how can i read console log from the server and have to show on UI of live executing processes or executed processes using java code.

Answer (score 0):

Use services of Amazon AWS to achieve your purpose with ease and less maintenance.
Services like ElasticSearch, Kibana, Cloudwatch can be used.

Refer to the documentation of usage on AWS site.
Example https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_ES_Stream.html

Comment: Ok, thanks for the response.
is there any other approaches except AWS to achieve purpose that you might know?

Comment: Yes. Too late to revert but your hosted ELK stack can be used too.